# Node struct calling itself

Tags: c++, pointers

The following code snippet, does compile:

```
struct node
{
    node * a; node * b; int count; 
    node (node * aa, node * bb, int count2){a=aa;b=bb;count=count2;}
};
```

**I was wondering why C++ would allow a pointer to a node inside a node struct** (which might as well be a node itself.. as you can just dereference it), instead of the actual node.. something like the below doesn't compile:

```
struct node
{
    node a; node b; int count; 
    node (node aa, node bb, int count2){a=aa;b=bb;count=count2;}
};
```

Also, later in my code, I tried to declare a node in the following manner:

```
node x=new node (NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Apparently, I need to make it something like:

```
node * x=new node (NULL, NULL, 0);
```

**I don't understand this.. why do you need to declare x as a pointer?**

Comment: node x = new node() is creating a stack variable, which can't point to heap

Comment: Ok, but why are pointers to nodes allowed within node structs, while actual nodes aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about trying to allocate enough memory for your struct. If the struct has a `node` inside of it, how big is a node? It's the size of an `int` plus `2 * sizeof(node)`. But how big is `node`??? It's recursive and there's no way to have a member of class `A` be of type `A`. It's like saying a person is made up of a head, a two arms, two legs, and a person. It just doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, a pointer is always some set size (usually 4 or 8 bytes). So how big is a `node`? It's `sizeof(int) + 2*sizeof(node*)`.

As for your second question, that's just how `new` works in C++. It returns a pointer to the allocated object.

It seems like maybe you are coming into this question with some Java background? In Java, pointers are not exposed to the programmer. The `new` keyword returns a reference, and you can have what appears to be a member of class `A` be an `A`. But that only works because the object instance members in Java are actually references, not the objects themselves.